Two-terminal PCB SMD component identification MK Z207
I have the PCB from a Garmin Nexus WSI box that a component with text MK Z207 next to power supply gets hot. It is not a fuse. It looks like a power diode or resistor. Black 2 x 2 mm, two contacts. Any idea what it is?
Thanks


logo appears to be ST microelectronics. but i could not get any search result on their site with keywords MK Z207. similar packaging style surge protection thyristors exist in their website. what are the two leads connected to? what is the peel off near the top right corner?
